# Magento integration testing: How to use fixtures instead of config.xml defaults?

Tags: php, magento, testing, phpunit

We're using [IvanChepurnyi's EcomDev_PHPUnit](https://github.com/IvanChepurnyi/EcomDev_PHPUnit), which seems to have some good features for writing unit and integration tests with Magento, including stated features about loading data to and from the database. Only, I can only get it to work halfway: I can get the data *to* the database, using fixtures, but my tests always get their data from unexpected places besides the database, like config.xml.

For example, suppose I create a simple model with an admin configuration piece:

app/code/community/My/Thing/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Thing>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </My_Thing>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <thing>
                <class>My_Thing_Helper</class>
            </thing>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <default>
        <thing>
            <it>
                <arbitrary>value</arbitrary>
            </it>
        </thing>
    </default>
    <phpunit>
        <suite>
            <modules>
                <My_Thing/>
            </modules>
        </suite>
    </phpunit>
</config>
```

app/code/community/My/Thing/etc/settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <thing translate="label" module="my_thing">
            <label>Thing</label>
        </thing>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <thing translate="label">
            <label>Thing Settings</label>
            <tab>thing</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <it translate="label">
                    <label>It</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>120</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <arbitrary translate="label">
                            <label>Arbitrary</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <validate>required-entry</validate>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </arbitrary>
                  </fields>
                </it>
            </groups>
        </thing>
    </sections>
</config>
```

app/code/community/My/Thing/Helper/Data.php:

```
<?php
class My_Thing_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    const CONFIG_IT_ARBITRARY = 'thing/it/arbitrary';

    /**
     * Get the arbitrary value.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getArbitrary()
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig(self::CONFIG_IT_ARBITRARY);
    }
}
```

app/code/community/My/Thing/Test/Helper/DataTest.php:

```
<?php
class My_Thing_Helper_DataTest extends EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case_Controller
{
    /**
     * The helper we're testing.
     */
    public $target = null;

    /**
     * Set up configuration for testing
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->target = Mage::helper('thing');
    }

    /**
     * Test that paths are joined correctly.
     * 
     * @loadFixture
     */
    public function testGetArbitrary()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(
            'something',
            $this->target->getArbitrary()
        );
    }
}
```

app/code/community/My/Thing/Test/Helper/DataTest/testGetArbitrary.yaml:

```
tables:
  core/config_data:
    - path: thing/it/arbitrary
      value: something
```

I realize the above test is contrived, but the point is that even if I create a fixture to set the "arbitrary" value to 'something', the test will fail because it gets the value from the config.xml default *even though* the 'something' value is in the database. Why is that? Is there some other trick to phpunit or EcomDev that I need to do in order to get the data from the test database, and not a cache or config.xml default?

By the way, if I run `phpunit` while constantly polling the test database for values, I *do* see `something` get inserted in the right place. The test just doesn't get the value from there.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com might be a better place.

Comment: @NathanMann thanks for the reply – http://magento.stackexchange.com seems to be for less code-related questions. This is about testing and coding, so I think it belongs on stackoverflow proper.

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue - I'm trying to programmatically rewrite etc/config.xml and then reload Magento, but running into weird issues:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734525/magento-extension-development-testing-multiple-config-xml-files-values-being