# Magento extension development - testing multiple config.xml files - values being cached?

Tags: php, unit-testing, magento

I am writing a test framework for a Magento extension I'm building.  The extension has a lot of configuration values stored in etc/config.xml under `<global><default>`.  The test framework instantiates an extension model and runs one of its methods.  However, first it copies a `config.xml` file to `/etc/config.xml`.  The idea is that the model is instantiated with a different config.xml every time, to test various configurations.  The test framework loops through half a dozen different `config.xml` files.

The problem - even if I re-bootstrap Magento, the extension model *always* instantiates with the config.xml data from whatever file was present when the routine was started.  I can see that the `etc/config.xml` file is indeed being changed on every iteration, and the changes show up in the global config when I do `Mage::getConfig()->loadModulesConfiguration->getNode('default/module_name')`.  It's like the extension is caching its config values on a per-run basis.  I'm executing the test file via PHP CLI.

Does anyone have any ideas on this one?  I'm stumped.  Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a workaround, but I'm still not sure what's causing the behavior.  In the model that I'm testing

```
$this->config = Mage::getStoreConfig('jd_premier/default');
```

returns the same (cached?) config data after I re-init Magento and call Mage::getConfig->reinit().  However,

```
$this->config = Mage::getConfig()->loadModulesConfiguration('config.xml')
                ->getNode('default/jd_premier/default');
```

returns the correct data from the newest version of config.xml.

No idea what's going on here, so if you can enlighten me I'm glad to accept it as the answer.